My react native Expo project is not connecting to my phone (using VScode)
I am suddenly getting the message in my VScode terminal:
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
I don't know why this is happening. My Expo Go app just says There was a problem loading the requested app. The internet connection appears to be offline. Make sure you're connected to the internet.
I'm definitely connected to wifi and have tried this on multiple wifi networks. I even tried building a new project but the problems persists, so it does not seem project specific. Any help would be greatly appreciated
